# How do I kill a crashed Mac App Store application that is running full-screen on OS X?

Tags: macos, crash, mac-app-store

I was able to login from another computer, used top to view the PID for the game, and then issued a kill command. Is there an easier way to recover without having to reboot the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try CMD-Option-Esc
 
Normally, that will bring the force quit dialog to the front and allow you to kill anything.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the killing didnt work and that is why you rebooted?

try kill -9 [pid]

Comment: No, killing it did work, but my wife and kids probably won't be able to use Terminal, ssh, top, and kill [pid] the next time it crashes.

Comment: good call but you could write a script that greps for the pid and then kills it =)

Comment: They still won't be able to use the Terminal, though ;)